# How to get BLE disconnection event in react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

I'm developing an Android app that needs to display when a BLE device disconnects from the phone so I would need to somehow intercept the disconnection event. I've tried using react-native-ble-manager that has a 'BleManagerDisconnectPeripheral' listener but it never fires, I couldn't find more details in the documentation but I suspect that this event only fires when a device that was previously connected using the library gets disconnected. Can anyone confirm this?
Is there another way to get handle of this event?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know when it's disconnected by e.g. another app or by the system? Like when a BLE keyboard is disconnected?